# What's the relationship among the many uses of the name "Praxis" in sci-fi?

Tags: history-of, names, praxis

Besides being the name of the Klingon moon destroyed in [Star Trek: The Undiscovered Country](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102975/),
there are at least five other uses of the name in sci-fi or gaming <sup>[citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praxis)</sup>

How are these uses related?

Comment: I obviously completely support this question.

Comment: @DougWarren:   I put the citation link to Wikipedia.   I just didn't list them in the question since I provided them in my answer.

Comment: Because it sounds cool?

Comment: He's some jerk on a website.

Comment: Sorry @Praxis, there's no badge for upvotes on a comment, I believe.

Comment: Unless I’ve been pushing these Q-Tips in too far I hear that Praxis makes perfect.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Background:** 
In the comments to this question,
[Who wrote "Ode to Spot" and Data's other poem?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96879/who-wrote-ode-to-spot-and-datas-other-poem)
@Praxis [questioned](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96879/who-wrote-ode-to-spot-and-datas-other-poem#comment228895_96899) why I hadn't accepted his answer yet and it was suggested that that it would move him to poetry when I did.   Well, this is my penance.  In doing the research to compose the response, and racking my brain over where to post it without being off-topic, I actually discovered there is an interesting question.   Surely there is no prohibition over asking an interesting question and choosing to answer in the form of a poem.

So, without further ado:

**"Ode to @Praxis" by @ThePopMachine**

> Praxis, oh, Praxis is a word of many meanings 
> The internet has many sites to help me with their gleanings.
>
> To start, it is a noun, which Wikipedia informs 
> Means the process by which a theory or idea takes a form.
>
> If you click on through [this link](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=praxis%20etymology) the etymology's for viewing 
> It comes from Greek through Latin and it lit'rally means "doing"
>
> I've also learnt that Praxis is a school of ideology 
> Specifically it's one of the Marxist genealogy.
>
> In Netherlands, I've read to reinstate your house's splendor, 
> Maybe you should journey to the Praxis Doe-Het-Zelf Center
>
> Many [links are red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praxis_(moth)), so therefore I am left to wonder: 
> Are all the Praxis genus moths endemic to Down Under?
>
> Now, looking more at sci-fi, on the *Sanctuary* series 
> Praxis lent its name a subterranean-type city
>
> In Robinson's *Mars* trilogy, the Praxis Corporation 
> is a metanat so large that it wields power over nations.
>
> The Klingon moon of Praxis is a place you dare not visit.
> Well, book your shuttle soon before you find that it now isn't.
>
> I'm not surprised that Lucas stole its planet death effect.
> (I also think that sci-fi scribes are partial to the X.)
>
> In the eponymic novel written by John Walter Williams, 
> The Praxis is the credo of a race who've enslaved humans.
>
> And lastly there's the user, to whom all should genuflect 
> For on scifi.SE, we know: @Praxis makes perfect.

Praxis recurs in many sci-fi contexts.

There appear to be a few reasons.

**(1)** Its meaning of 'putting theory into practice' is just vague but specific enough to be applied to almost any thing or idea.   It's like "[the method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_acting)" or if named your philosophy The Philosophy.   So since sci-fi deals with ideas, and lofty scenarios with entities that apply those ideas, it's easy to apply this term.

**(2)**The [Praxis School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praxis_School) of Marxist philosophy originated in the 1960s, so may have informed many SF writers during their schooling or afterwards.

**(3)** It has a futuristic, retro, or cool feel because of the [X](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/this-britain/xrated-what-is-so-special-about-the-letter-x-423333.html) and the 'is/us' suffix (Ex. Locutus, Optimus Prime, Crosis).

In some respects, [nexus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus) is a very similar word.   It has a similar morphology and its meaning is just general yet specific enough (a connection linking two or more things; a central and most important point or place) to recur many times in sci-fi and [gaming](https://www.reddit.com/r/Civcraft/comments/2gih82/announcing_praxis_a_standalone_societybuilding/).

In Sanctuary, [Praxis](http://sanctuary.wikia.com/wiki/Praxis)  "is a vast metropolis built with materials and technology far in advance of anything available on the surface .. founded some eight thousand years ago by humans of "great and extraordinary intelligence"  ".   So both **(1)** and **(3)** apply.

In the [Mars trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_trilogy), "Praxis Corporation paves a new way of 'democratic businesses' " and therefore is the embodiment of a new theory.   So similarly, **(1)** and **(3)** apply.

In [Star Trek: The Undiscovered Country](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country), [Praxis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Praxis) is a moon of the Klingon homeworld Q'onos used for energy production.  While one may argue that there could be ties to **(1)**, Memory Alpha suggests that the connection is through **(2)**:

> The explosion of Praxis is loosely based on the [Chernobyl disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster), one of several factors leading to the breakdown of the [Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Union). ([Captains' Logs: The Unauthorized Complete Trek Voyages](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Captains%27_Logs:_The_Unauthorized_Complete_Trek_Voyages), pp. 137-138) Likewise, the word "Praxis" is employed in the writings of [Karl Marx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Marx), meaning active rather than merely theoretical socialism.

This having been said, it doesn't seem this the name *Praxis* for the moon is intended in universe to carry the meaning of praxis.  It wouldn't make sense for the Klingon moon to have a name in English that means anything, and it doesn't appear the the name *Praxis* is intended to be the translation of a Klingon word.   While the word doesn't seem particularly Klingon to our modern ears after all the Klingon development in *Star Trek: The Next Genetration* and *Deep Space Nine*, it appears to be case of **(3)**.  The fact that the name [*Worf*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Worf_(Colonel)), which also originates in *Star Trek: The Undiscovered Country*, doesn't seem particularly Klingon by modern standards lends credence to the assertion that *Worf* and *Praxis* are both just intended to be normal Klingon names before the whole Klingon morphology and phonology became more developed.

Interestingly the effect of depicting a three-dimensional explosion with an expanding 2D ring originates in [Star Trek: The Undiscovered Country](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country)(1991) and is known as [the Praxis effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praxis_effect).  It enjoyed fairly common use over the next few years, in popular sci-fi films.   This includes 1994's [Stargate](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111282/), 1996's [Independence Day](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116629/), the 1997 DVD Special Editions of [Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/) and [Star Wars Episode VI: Return of the Jedi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086190/), and 1998's [Armageddon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120591/)
[image][image]

(Related: [What inspired the Praxis effect?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13720/3823))

In the 2002 novel [*The Praxis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Praxis), the Praxis is the philosophy based "on total obedience and hierarchy" of the Shaa, "a powerful race that have ruled the Empire for thousands of years, having subjugated humans and other races."   So this is an instance of **(1)**.   It is also likely that **(3)** applies, because the novel contains an insectoid race, the *Naxids*, which one will note also have similar morphology to *Praxis*, therefore suggesting the futuristic quality of both words was a factor.

So, to summarize, based on evidence found so far, there does not appear to be any connection among the various sci-fi uses of the name *Praxis*, except via the original meaning of the word and its sounds, which both make it attractive to sci-fi writers.

However, the scifi.stackexcange.com user [@Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294/praxis)  does appear to be named after the Klingon moon Praxis.   His 1st, 2nd, 6th, 7th, 10th, and 11th most commonly used [tags](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/40294/praxis?tab=tags) (and 18 of his top 52) are related to Star Trek.   Furthermore, his avatar picture is shared with the Memory Alpha page on the moon [Praxis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Praxis)

[image]

Comment: Calling @Praxis

Comment: Note: criticisms of meaning, meter, or rhyme are not valid reasons for downvote.

Comment: About the word occurring in the writings of Marx: Well yeah, it's a [common word in German](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Praxis).

Comment: @Praxis, I just realized that writing a poem about you in the style of "Ode to Spot" is essentially equating you to my pet.

Comment: You have to include the word "Nomenclature" in it somewhere, lol. @Praxis

Comment: @JMFB:  I did at one point,  but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: That's fine, so long as you feed me and change my litter regularly.

Comment: @Praxis:  Good boy!   Who's a nice pussy?!

Comment: Another great example is found in Stephenson's [Anathem](http://anathem.wikia.com/wiki/Praxis)

Comment: *I cannot comprehend @JMFB's motivator /
It seems he can't see past the poem's lack of "nomenclature"*

Comment: Is the blue called link just for me in orange?^^

Comment: If I could give you more than a +1 for this masterpiece, I would.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard:    *Poetry is work / Not enough recognition / Damn rep cap limit*

Comment: @Zaibis:   I wrote the line about red links first, but that is okay because it's about how red and red links are rendered in Wikipedia.   Then I wrote the line about the blue link before I pasted everything in SE without realizing SE renders links this way.

Comment: Changed 'this blue' -> 'through this'

Comment: @CreationEdge:  That linked page is not very clear to me.   'Praxis' capitalized.   The definition doesn't seem very accurate unless it's used in the book a different way its basic definition.   And it says "the Earth term for praxis is techonology"  Is that a cute way to give a synonym or is the term used by some aliens in the book and not humans or what?  Essentially I don't understand what the page is saying or how high quality it is.

Comment: @CreationEdge:   Botton line:   I can't tell if that link is a dubious quality or it really represents the usage in that book

Comment: @ThePopMachine If you haven't read the book, I can see it not making sense. It about a futuristic parallel Earth, and their literal word for technology is praxis. There may be Capital Emphasis in the book for certain uses, but the general use is not more capitalized than *technology* would be. The book is filled with words similar to our own or replacement to our own (even the title Anathem is Anathema + Anthem)

Comment: @CreationEdge:   Thanks -- I will edit this in.

Comment: @CreationEdge:   Is the word used both in-universe and in the text?  On in the text only by reference to their use of the word?

Comment: @ThePopMachine It's used in the book directly by the characters and the narrator, and very frequently, any time you or I would say "technology". The writing style of the book requires you to guess at the meanings for many of these words (as English equivalents are not used), or wait until you read a selected excerpt from an in-universe dictionary (such excerpts being provided at the beginnings of chapters).

Comment: @CreationEdge:   It is given in one such dictionary?   DO you have an excerpt?

Comment: OMG, what a fantastic answer!

Comment: @Praxis, ThePopMachine - another one: in the [*Ocean Girl* TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ocean_Girl_episodes), PRAXIS stands for the Preventative Response And eXtraterritorial Intelligence Service.

Comment: @randal'thor : Nice find.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Praxis is a German word (hence its use by Karl Marx) with several meanings, all of which make it a good word for the examples above. Here are some of the German uses;

Arztpraxis; the location where a doctor or a group of doctors ply their business.
empfohlene Praxis; the recommended way of doing something
Praxisjahr; on-the-job training, internship for one year

(Not normally used for practicing something, that is Uebung.)

As said above, Kim Stanley Robinson used it in the Mars books, one example of Robinson actually getting German right. And it is a natty word with an x in the middle.

Edit: In the book it is first introduced as the name of a Swiss organisation

Comment: Praxis is greek. The greek word has made it into the german language because it was used by greek philosophers.

Comment: @Cubic Is this speculation or do you have a reference?   The term in English supposedly comes through medieval Latin.  I'm just asking so I can make my answer more compete.